# Trouble creating a new jekyll site: "Could not locate Gemfile or .bundle/ directory"

Tags: rubygems, jekyll, github-pages

I am trying to create a Jekyll site hosted on GitHub Pages, and have been following the [GitHub Pages tutorial](https://help.github.com/en/github/working-with-github-pages/creating-a-github-pages-site-with-jekyll#creating-your-site) to do so.

When I run `bundle exec jekyll 4.0.1 new` in the terminal (as in step 7 in the tutorial, 4.0.1 being the version of jekyll on my machine), it fails with `Could not locate Gemfile or .bundle/ directory`.

I've double checked the dependencies with `jekyll -v`, `git --version`, `bundler -v`, `ruby -v`, `gem -v` and all are installed so I'm not sure where I've gone wrong.

I'm running macOS 10.15.4.

Answer (score 15):

I had the same problem recently (and actually came across this question while searching for an answer).

Following the instructions on [jekyllrb.com/tutorials/using-jekyll-with-bundler](https://jekyllrb.com/tutorials/using-jekyll-with-bundler/) helped me get my site running. I think `bundle init` is the command you need to avoid the error you see (it creates a Gemfile), but then there are other errors, so I had to run the following commands to get my website working.

```
$ cd my-jekyll-website
$ bundle init
$ bundle add jekyll
$ bundle exec jekyll new --force --skip-bundle .
```

Then I followed the GitHub tutorial's steps to update the `gem "github-pages"` line in the Gemfile, and then I ran `bundle install`. After that, `bundle exec jekyll serve` worked, and I could see the new website locally.

I am using Ubuntu 20.04, so hopefully these instructions work for you too.